# Keyence camera triggering via ethernet

Tags: c

Could anyone please tell me how to trigger a KEYENCE camera (CV-X150FP) over ethernet? I tried "1" "F" "000F" etc., usual stuff i can think of.

I am sending it in String format, as RobotStudio wont let me do much else.

Any ideas? I searched threw all the manuals i could find, and then some more.

Thank you!